# Redis and PHP (Rediska) intersect on set

Tags: php, nosql, redis, social-graph, rediska

I'm trying to do some tricks with a graph (node/edges) dataset. In this case a set of data where person x follows person y (direct relation).  I want to load this data (from a mysql table) into redis (have it running). I've chosen to use [Rediska](http://rediska.geometria-lab.ru/documentation/get-started/) because I use PHP and it seems stable.

Rediska has very limited documentation and examples, so I was hoping you guys can help me. I have little to no experience with noSQL, especially the naming conventions (userid:1:follows = 2?).

My questions:

- how do I load a set of person x follows person y data into a redis data set
- how do I find the "intersect" (SINTER) and end up with a php array (so I get person X and person Y both follow (a result set) of people))
- and last not but leasy, how would I 'traverse' this graph data to find a relation: person x -> person y -> person z (person x and person z both follow person y, hence person z is in the result set)

Comment: Just as an aside: rediska is not the recommended way to connect from php to redis as you can see here: http://redis.io/clients its best to use either PHPRedis (a C extension) or Predis (written in plain PHP).

Answer (score 1):

Q1 **How do you load a set of person x follows person y data into a redis data set**?
you need to use a set as the data structure and throw in there the indexes of people following. For example, suppose you have 10 users with ids from 1 to 10 and you want to say that person:3, person:5 and person:10 are all following person:2 ...

```
sadd person:2:followers 3
sadd person:2:followers 5
sadd person:2:followers 10
```

This would give you a set of followers for person 2 containing the ids 3, 5 and 10. To query this data...

```
smembers person:2:followers
```

Q2 **How do I find the intersect and end up with a php array(person:x:followers && person:y:followers)**?

```
sinterstore tmp person:2:followers person:8:followers
sort tmp get person:*->name get person:*->age
```

Q3 **how would you traverse this graph data to find a relation: person x -> person y -> person z (person x and person z both follow person y, hence person z is in the result set)**?

```
This question does not make sense (to me at least). Could you explain or reword it?
```